# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() returning blank image in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigraphicscontext

I've been successfully using the function below to take snapshots of UIViews, however, now that I'm using it inside a UITableViewCell, it no longer works.

```
static func pictureTaker(_ rawView: UIView) -> UIImageView {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rawView.bounds.size, false, 0)
        rawView.drawHierarchy(in: rawView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        let viewImage = UIImageView(image: screenshot)
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        viewImage.frame = rawView.frame
        return viewImage
    }
```

Here is a trimmed down version of the function I'm using to populate the UITableViewCell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = gamesHolder.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! StandardGameCell
        let row = indexPath.row

        let boardPreviewTemplate = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.previewBoard.frame.width, height: cell.previewBoard.frame.height))
        GameManagement.setupBoard(boardPreviewTemplate, boardItems: gamesArray[row].board)

        let gamePicture = PageManagement.pictureTaker(boardPreviewTemplate)
        gamePicture.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: gamePicture.frame.width, height: gamePicture.frame.height)

        //Removing preview board items and replacing with picture
        cell.previewBoard.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
        cell.previewBoard.addSubview(gamePicture)

        return cell
    }
```

In the above `tableView` function, I'm programmatically creating a new view to replicate `cell.previewBoard`, but I also tried directly snapshotting `cell.previewBoard` and that didn't work either.  I think the issue has something to do with the timing of the UITableViewCell loading.

I'm also 100% positive that the function is returning an image (but a blank one) and that it's where I'm intending it to be.  If I change `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rawView.bounds.size, false, 0)` to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rawView.bounds.size, true, 0)`, the returned image shows up as entirely black.

As one final note, I discovered that `boardPreviewPicture.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)` would return an image, but it made scrolling through the UITableView very slow.  Maybe there is another workaround where I can use `snapshotView()` instead.

Comment: You may want to rethink your design pattern. For one thing, creating / adding / removing a cell's subviews in `cellForRowAt` is generally inadvisable.  What all does `GameManagement.setupBoard()` do? You might be able to streamline things there... And why are you adding/removing `UIImageView`s? And maybe other views (looking at your `.subviews.forEach` loop)? Maybe show a couple images of what you're shooting for...

Comment: I'm generating previews of existing boards for a game I'm creating.  The reason I need to take the snapshot is that each game piece is comprised of multiple views (that was necessary to get the look I want) and there are multiple game pieces per board preview.  Because each cell only takes up part of the screen, I end up having several hundred views per screen, which makes for very choppy scrolling.  By getting a snapshot, I can limit it down to a smaller number of views and get smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem. What I noticed is that when `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` is called inside `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, the result from `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` is blank. Take note that in the documentation it is stated that `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`:

> This function may be called from any thread of your app.

However, the solution that I discovered is to call it inside the main thread. In your case, maybe you can do something like:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let gamePicture = PageManagement.pictureTaker(boardPreviewTemplate)
    gamePicture.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: gamePicture.frame.width, height: gamePicture.frame.height)

    //Removing preview board items and replacing with picture
    cell.previewBoard.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
    cell.previewBoard.addSubview(gamePicture)
}
```